# Trying to add delay in outputlink onmouseover

Tags: javascript, outputlink, mousehover

I'm trying to add a 1 second delay when user hovers over an outputlink. For now window.open triggers an immediate popup of a window. Here's what I tried to delay for 1 second..

1st Attempt:

```
 <apex:outputLink value="" onmouseover="awin=window.open('vf_OrderLines?id={!o.id}','My Lines','height=300, width=1000, left=400, scrollbars=yes'), awin.setTimeout=(awin,1000);" onmouseout="awin.close();">{!o.Orders__c}</apex:outputLink>
```

2nd Attemt:

```
 <a href="#" onMouseOver="setTimeout(window.open('vf_OrderLines?id={!o.id}','My Lines','height=300, width=1000, left=400, scrollbars=yes'),1000);">{!o.Orders__c}</a>
```

So far no errors in javascript console. Let me know if there is a way for this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your 2nd attempt work? what happens? did you check the js console?

Comment: Second attempt also doesn't work. But thank god there's an error :) SyntaxError: missing ] after element list.......no idea what it tells though

Comment: please try to wrap you window.open with a closure onMouseOver="setTimeout( function() { window.open('vf_OrderLines?id={!o.id}','My Lines','height=300, width=1000, left=400, scrollbars=yes'); } ,1000);"

Comment: In my experience that setTimeout works best like setTimeout( function { youCode; }, 1000 ); - and I like inline, too. Why a lot of code for such a little thing?

Comment: Awesome! your above solution did the trick. Could you add this as answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hat this already in my answere. But to point it out more explicitly, I update my answer with an additional hint. Would be cool if you could accept it as best answer now - or let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice. Accepted, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delays in JavaScript are typically done with [Window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) like this:

```
Window.setTimeout( function() {
    // your delayed code comes here
}, 2000  );
```

Beware that in my experience setTimeout() works best with a closure like setTimeout( function { youCode; }, 1000 ); - putting your code directly without that function(){}-wrapper into setTimeout often results into very wired JS errors.

Now in the event, you can either call a function containing the setTimeout() or you press it all into a one-liner an push it inline into the onmouseover="" attribute. Going inline might end up in double and triple escapes for quotes and poor readability.

An other alternative is to use event listeners. E.g. with the [jQuery on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Therefore you should a `styleClass` tag to identify the link easily with selectors. Pattern would be the same: in the on() callback you use setTimeout().

Answer (score 3):

Please see a working example below. This's not a good practice to use inline scripts, thus I recomend to move it to separate files.

```
<apex:page id="pageid" standardcontroller="account">
  <apex:form id="formid">
      <apex:pageblock id="pbid">
          <apex:pageblocksection id="pbsid">

              <apex:outputLink id="oLink" value="test?id={!Account.id}">{!Account.Id}</apex:outputLink>

          </apex:pageblocksection>
      </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript">
      var openWin = function() {
           awin = window.open('test?id={!Account.id}','My Lines','height=300, width=1000, left=400, scrollbars=yes');
      }

      $(function(){
        var timer;
        var el = document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageid.formid.pbid.pbsid.oLink}');
        el.onmouseover = function(){
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                openWin(el);
            }, 2500);
        }
        el.onmouseout = function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            awin.close();
        }
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi! @pavel thanks for your elaborated answer. I appreciate your help!